# VBA Mouse Button code works only on Button 1 not Button 2

Tags: vba

VBA is in a Rockwell Viw SE application.

I have some code that is working but only if linked to mouse button 1 and I really need it to be a button 2 or right mouse click function. The code is on the MouseUp sub and is used to move an object on screen. I’m sure it’s just a quirk of VBA but thought there may be a workaround.

Mouse button 2 will work but only if released over the same object as when clicked, mouse button 1 don't care where on the screen the release happens.

```
 Private Sub Box1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As DisplayClientEx.gfxMouseButtonConstants, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
    Dim XObject As Object
    Dim YObject As Object

    FindNumStart = InStrRev(Box1.ToolTipText, "[") + 1
    FindNumEnd = InStrRev(Box1.ToolTipText, "]")
    BoxNum = Mid(Box1.ToolTipText, FindNumStart, (FindNumEnd - FindNumStart))
    Set XObject = ThisDisplay.FindElement("XW" & BoxNum)
    Set YObject = ThisDisplay.FindElement("YW" & BoxNum)

    PNum = Box1.ToolTipText & ", " & Chr(34) & Mid(Box1.ToolTipText, 1, (FindNumStart - 14)) & "BoxPosition[" & BoxNum & Chr(34)
        If Button = 2 Then
            GetCursorPos Mouse
            ScreenToClient Me.Application.WindowHandle, Mouse
            Box1.Left = Mouse.X - 40
            Box1.Top = Mouse.Y - 78
            XObject.Value = Box1.Left
            XObject.Download
            YObject.Value = Box1.Top
            YObject.Download
        ElseIf Button = 1 Then
            GetCursorPos Mouse
            ExecuteCommand Cmd & " /X" & Box1.Left - 68 & " /Y" & Box1.Top + 100 & " /T " & PNum
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're listening for a `MouseUp` in `Box1`'s handler. Why should it respond if it's not over `Box1`? I'm not exactly clear what you're trying to do - what does it mean for this to "work" v. "not work"?

Comment: If I click on the box with button 1 I can move it anywhere on the screen. If I click on it with button 2 it must be released over the object clicked. I guess it should not work with either button but it does.